# How to get the DropDown selected value and not work out Assign Button in controller in MVC3?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Hi all i have to get the selected value from dropdown into my post method in controller and not work out Assign Button  ..how can i do this

```
MY modelcode
------------

 namespace Gridview_BugTracker.Models
{
    public class BugTracker_DataHelper
    {

        public static List<BugTracker_DataHelper> GetList{get;set;}

           public int ProjectId { get; set; }
           public string projectName { get; set; }           
           public string Description { get; set; }
           public  string status { get; set; }
           public int EmployeId { get; set; }
           public string EmployeName { get; set; }
           public bool selectChkbox { get; set; }  


      }      

   }
```

### my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult DropCheckInsert(int ProjectId, string EmployeName, FormCollection collection, BugTracker_DataHelper bughelperdata)
        {    

            var modeldropdownlist = new BugTracker_DataHelper();
           SqlConnection Assignworkconn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS");
            {
                Assignworkconn.Open();
                SqlCommand insertcommande = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert", Assignworkconn);
                insertcommande.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@EmployeId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeName;
                insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@projectId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProjectId;

                insertcommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return View(modeldropdownlist);

}
}

}


My View code
------------------

<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>AssignProject</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm()) 
     { %>      
    <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>       
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Projects</legend>
                    <%: Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectId, "--Select Project--")%>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectId")%>                


                    <fieldset style="color:Blue;">                 

                    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>  
                  <div>
                  <%:Html.CheckBox(item.EmployeName) %>
                  <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeName) %>
                  </div>                 
                 <%} %>



             <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
             </p> 

        </fieldset>
       <%-- @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Contact.StateId, new SelectList(Model.States, "Id", "Name", @Model.Contact.StateId))--%>  


    <%} %>


    </div>
</body>
```

now i want to get the selected value projectId Parameter and  in my postmedthod and not work Assign Button. Can anyone help me with how i should do this?